# What dependencies should I apply dependency injection?

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I am new to Dependency Injection in Android and I am trying to learn it with Hilt. I understand the importance of Dependency Injection in our apps. But when I tried to apply Hilt in my app, I wonder if do we also need to apply DI in other dependencies of an activity like `Buttons`, `AppBarConfiguration`, `NavController`, etc. I learned that if we have dependencies from 3rd party libraries, we need to specify it in a `@Module` class and use `@Provides` annotation. How about in classes built-in in android? Do I also need to specify it in a `@Module` class? If not, why?

I know this is a newbie question, but I hope someone will try to explain it to a newbie like me. I know there might something in DI that I do not understand yet

Comment: See: http://misko.hevery.com/2008/09/30/to-new-or-not-to-new/